# Each loop with jQuery data attributes not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops

```
<ul class='list-container'>
<li class='list-item' data-level='parent_level'>
    <ul>
        <li data-level='child_level'> Child 1</li>
        <li data-level='child_level'> Child 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class='list-item' data-level='parent_level'>
    <ul>
        <li data-level='child_level'> Child 3</li>
        <li data-level='child_level'> Child 4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is my HTML code.

I want to print each element in child list. I want to use data-attributes for the same.
I tried fetching elements with class. It's working fine.

```
var list = $('list-container');
list.each(function(){console.log($(this).html())});
```

With this code I got Following HTML content in output.

```
 <li class="list-item" data-level="parent_level">
  <ul>
    <li data-level="child_level"> Child 1</li>
    <li data-level="child_level"> Child 2</li>
  </ul>
</li>


<li class="list-item" data-level="parent_level">
  <ul>
    <li data-level="child_level"> Child 3</li>
    <li data-level="child_level"> Child 4</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

When I tried same thing using data attributes as follow:

```
var list= $.find("[data-level='parent_level']");
list.forEach(function(){console.log($(this).html())});
```

Output of log is 'undefined'.

Replacing '.forEach' with '.each' giving error as '.each is not a function'.

```
list.each(function(){console.log($(this).html())});
```

Comment: Did you try using `$("[data-level='parent_level']").each(...)`?

Comment: $("[data-level='parent_level']").each(...) worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use `.find()` just call it like `var list = $("[data-level='parent_level']");`

Even better, `$("[data-level='parent_level']").each()` will save you a line.

If you don't want the `ul` that it currently prints, just write: `$("[data-level='parent_level'] ul")`

```js
var list = $("[data-level='parent_level']");


list.each(function() {
  console.log($(this).html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='list-container'>
  <li class='list-item' data-level='parent_level'>
    <ul>
      <li data-level='child_level'> Child 1</li>
      <li data-level='child_level'> Child 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class='list-item' data-level='parent_level'>
    <ul>
      <li data-level='child_level'> Child 3</li>
      <li data-level='child_level'> Child 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some selector issues in your script, check updated snippet below..

```js
var list = $('.list-container');
list.each(function(){console.log($(this).html())});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='list-container'>
<li class="list-item" data-level="parent_level">
  <ul>
    <li data-level="child_level"> Child 1</li>
    <li data-level="child_level"> Child 2</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>


<li class="list-item" data-level="parent_level">
  <ul>
    <li data-level="child_level"> Child 3</li>
    <li data-level="child_level"> Child 4</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: You've missed out the `ul` with the actual css class you're targetting - so no output from `console.log`